# How to avoid CORS error when drawing image onto canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dropbox

Currently working on a project for my coding bootcamp. I am trying to overlay bandaids on an image of a bear and I am trying to use canvas to check the color of the area that they click to ensure that they dont put bandaids on the white space around the actual image.

As you can see I tried to solve my original contamination error by hosting the image on dropbox and then using the raw link with cross origin anonymous. My instructor told me to try this. However now I am getting an error during the drawing of the image onto the canvas. It says:

"Redirect from 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxb6ndsf71jvy25/myBear.png?raw=1' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Can someone help me out with a simple solution?

Here is my HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="1331" height="941">Helllo</canvas>

<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxb6ndsf71jvy25/myBear.png?raw=1" onload="draw()" style="display: none" id="theBear" crossorigin="anonymous">

<img src="assets/images/bandaids/001-medical-3.png" class="bandAids">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

Relevant JavaScript:

```
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("theBear");
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  console.log("drew image");
};

$(document).on("click","#canvas", function(event) {
  var c = this.getContext('2d');
  var p = c.getImageData(event.pageX, event.pageY, 1, 1).data; 
  var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
  console.log(hex);
  database.ref().child("bandAids").push({
    xCord: event.pageX,
    yCord: event.pageY,
    bandAid: myBandAid, 
  })
  console.log(event);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution but unsure if it applies to all related issues and don't really get why it works.

Just change www.dropbox.com to dl.dropboxusercontent.com in your url.

Found Here:

https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/CORS-issue-when-trying-to-download-shared-file/td-p/82466

Comment: It works because dropbox does send the correct CORS headers from within this origin.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `crossOrigin` attribute on the image:

```
function loadImage(src, cb) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        cb(this);
    }
    image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    image.src = src;
}
```

...

```
var img = document.getElementById("theBear");
loadImage(img.src, function(image) {
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
}
```

If it's not working you should host the image on your own webserver or an imagehoster like [imgur](https://imgur.com/) and set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header accordingly.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean? Haven't I already done this in my html?

Comment: Yep you have, i missed that. Then you have to go for option 2.